# How to make top round corner surface with image on top of the screen with Jetpack Compose

Tags: android, android-jetpack-compose

I wanna make a screen like this,

[image]

But my code is not working as expected.
The top image is cut and the icon is not on the top image.

[image]

My code:

```
    Scaffold { innerPadding ->
        LazyColumn(
            modifier = Modifier
                .padding(innerPadding)
                .clip(shape = RoundedCornerShape(15.dp, 15.dp, 0.dp, 0.dp))
                .background(Color.Red),
            verticalArrangement = Arrangement.spacedBy(8.dp)
        ) {
            item {
                Card(
                    modifier = Modifier.size(size = 88.dp),
                    shape = RoundedCornerShape(13.dp),
                    colors = CardDefaults.cardColors(Color.Black),
                    border = BorderStroke(width = 3.dp, color = Color.Gray),
                ) {
                    Box(
                        modifier = Modifier.fillMaxSize()
                            .size(size = 54.dp)
                            .background(Color.Black)
                    )
                }
            }
        }
    }
```

How to fix this?

I tried using a custom Layout and it works better, but I can't clip the top borders correctly.

Comment: Is this a Bottom sheet or a static UI component in the Scaffold?

Comment: @Abhimanyu it's static. Not a bottom sheet, just a view

Answer (score 1):

You can use a `Box` and `offset` Modifier to achieve the required layout.

---

Example

[image]

Sample code

```
@Composable
fun BoxOffsetSample() {
    Box(
        modifier = Modifier
            .fillMaxSize()
            .background(Color.Yellow),
    ) {
        Box(
            Modifier
                .fillMaxWidth()
                .align(Alignment.BottomCenter)
        ) {
            Box(
                Modifier
                    .clip(
                        RoundedCornerShape(
                            topStart = 13.dp,
                            topEnd = 13.dp,
                            bottomEnd = 0.dp,
                            bottomStart = 0.dp,
                        )
                    )
                    .background(Color.Red)
                    .fillMaxWidth()
                    .height(200.dp)
            )
            Box(
                modifier = Modifier
                    .offset(13.dp, (-20).dp)
                    .clip(RoundedCornerShape(8.dp))
                    .size(54.dp)
                    .background(Color.Black),
            )
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: this is a good solution but i wouldn't use hard coded values for offset instead i would have a method to calculate the offset based on something like the height of image divided by 2 or something like this, so that it looks the same on all devices

Comment: @AymanAit, This is an example. The question does not have enough info on the requirement for placement and spacing. The answer is only the first line - "Use Boxes with Modifiers and offset"